# Ruby on Rails query for a given set of dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to write a query for my Rails API that will return the total number of hours of job applications that are accepted per month for a given set of dates.

Table: Job, JobApplication

Job has many JobApplication

JobApplication has a field status "SUCCESS" if matched

Start Date: Jul 16 2015

Is it possible to have it return {Jul 16: 100, Aug 16: 200, .... } ?

I am quite confused. Any help would be appreciated.

This query would give the number of successful Job Applications within a date range.

```
JobApplication.where(status: "SUCCESS").("created_at < ? ", Jul 16).("created_at < ? ", Aug 15)
```

JobApplication.job.duration would give the number of hours for that job.

I am not sure how to put them together and then loop through the dates.

My expect results is something like this:

```
{Jul 16: 100, Aug 16: 200, .... }
```

Comment: Hey what is your data and what you are expecting?? put some sample data?? and what you are tried??

Comment: Hi Vishal, pls see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can try this way:

```
JobApplication.joins(:job).where(status: "SUCCESS").where(job_applications => {:created_at => [state_date..end_date]}).group(:created_at).sum("jobs.duration")
```

It will Return you result like

```
{Date => total_duration, :date => total_duration}
```

If You want you can convert date to specific format like `DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%m-%y")` so just put `group(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m-%y"))`. It will remove your time part from timestamp in `mysql` and returns data daywise

Comment: it's giving me PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "--- !ruby/range

Comment: you can used `PG` related datetime function

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
data = JobApplication.where(status: 'SUCCESS').group(:start_date).select('start_date, count(*), sum(duration) as sum')
```

should do the trick, if i understood your question right. This will return JobApplication instances with `sum` set

Perhaps it is easier to run a pure SQL query:

```
SELECT start_date, count(*), sum(duration) FROM job_applications WHERE status LIKE 'SUCCESS' GROUP BY start_date
```

Comment: sorry i meant for a month, starting jul 16 to aug 15, not just for one day and duration is in the job table, do i need to include(job)?